# Spotify web player gives Websocket error on raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, websocket, raspberry-pi, spotify

I am trying to set up spotify player to my raspberry pi. I have codes that work's like a charm on my macbook/chrome but the same codes wont work on raspbian/chromium.

I am getting following errors:

```
Error while parsing the 'allow' attribute: 'encrypted-media' is an invalid feature name.

{message: "Failed to initialize player"}  script.js:44

WebSocket connection to 'wss://gew-dealer.spotify.com/?access_token=removed_my_token' 
failed: Error in connection establishment: net:: ERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED

{message: "Authentication failed"}   script.js:45
```

Here is my script.js:

```
const hash = window.location.hash
.substring(1)
.split('&')
.reduce(function (initial, item) {
  if (item) {
    var parts = item.split('=');
    initial[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
  }
  return initial;
}, {});
window.location.hash = '';

// Set token
let _token = hash.access_token;

const authEndpoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';

// Replace with your app's client ID, redirect URI and desired scopes
const clientId = 'removed_my_client_id';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:1337';
const scopes = [
  'streaming',
  'user-read-birthdate',
  'user-read-private',
  'user-read-email',
  'user-modify-playback-state'
];

// If there is no token, redirect to Spotify authorization
if (!_token) {
    window.location = `${authEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join('%20')}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`;
}

// Set up the Web Playback SDK

window.onSpotifyPlayerAPIReady = () => {
  const player = new Spotify.Player({
    name: 'Web Playback SDK Template',
    getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(_token); }
  });

  // Error handling
  player.on('initialization_error', e => console.error(e));
  player.on('authentication_error', e => console.error(e));
  player.on('account_error', e => console.error(e));
  player.on('playback_error', e => console.error(e));

  // Playback status updates
  player.on('player_state_changed', state => {
    console.log(state)
    $('#current-track').attr('src', state.track_window.current_track.album.images[0].url);
    $('#current-track-name').text(state.track_window.current_track.name);
  });

  // Ready
  player.on('ready', data => {
    console.log('Ready with Device ID', data.device_id);

    // Play a track using our new device ID
    play(data.device_id);
  });

  // Connect to the player!
  player.connect();
}

// Play a specified track on the Web Playback SDK's device ID
function play(device_id) {
  $.ajax({
   url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=" + device_id,
   type: "PUT",
   data: '{"uris": ["spotify:track:5ya2gsaIhTkAuWYEMB0nw5"]}',
   beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + _token );},
   success: function(data) { 
     console.log(data)
   }
  });
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Spotify Web Playback SDK Template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://sp-bootstrap.global.ssl.fastly.net/8.0.0/sp-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Include the Web Playback SDK -->
    <script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>

    <!-- Include our Javascript -->
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body class="container">
    <h1 class="text-salmon">Spotify Web Playback SDK Template</h1>
    <h4>This app uses the implicit grant authorization flow to get an access token and initialise the Web Playback SDK. It then uses the Spotify Connect Web API to play a song.</h4>
    <p>If everything is set up properly, you should hear some music!</p>
    <img id="current-track"/>
    <h3 id="current-track-name"></h3>
    <a class="btn btn-salmon btn-lg" href="https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spotify-web-playback">Get started!</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

**This code should do:**

- Initialize the web player
- Select one hard coded song
- Play the song
- Show the image

I have absolutely no idea what could be the problem here. I have been trying a lot of things to fix this but the problem is that i don't know what causes this so i have been just doing stuff without any idea is it going to help. So my question is how i can make this work on raspberry?

Comment: Hi there i am having the same issue is there any update or did you find any solution